# binding jquery ui datetimepicker to dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic rows being created that I need to bind to a jquery ui datetimepicker , binding to normal is fine, no idea how to bind a jquery ui widget though.

Thanks In Advance

Hi all.
managed to get it resolved by doing the following in my jquery

```
$("#routemap").delegate(".date", "focusin", function () {
   $(this).datetimepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true
   });
});
```